# Alert is just showing up as the 'Starting my ${subject} homework.' not 'Starting my math homework.'

Tags: javascript

```js
function doHomework(subject) {
    alert("Starting my ${subject} homework.");
}
doHomework("math");
```

*I have been running this code on my console and the subject is not changing, Any idea why?*

Answer (score 1):

it needs to be a template literal using back ticks ` not quotes "

```
function doHomework(subject) {
    alert(`Starting my ${subject} homework.`);
}
doHomework("math");
```

Comment: beautiful! Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use `` instead of `""`

```js
function doHomework(subject) {
    alert(`Starting my ${subject} homework.`);
}
doHomework("math");
```

Comment: Good stuff!! Thank you sir.

Answer (score 1):

As stated in [the documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals):

> Template literals are literals **delimited with backtick (`) characters**,
> allowing for multi-line strings, for string interpolation with
> embedded expressions, and for special constructs called tagged
> templates.

```js
function doHomework(subject) {
    alert(`Starting my ${subject} homework.`);
}
doHomework("math");
```

Comment: Needed some reading! I appreciate the help. Thank you!